# How to implement Polly correctly in my code to avoid freezing

Tags: c#, polly

I'm having a problem with Polly causing the thread to freeze.
As you can see under the GetData() method is going to throw an exception. I want to do is to continue to Dostuff1 and 2 when exceptions occur in the GetData() method in DoStuff(); But it seems like after retrying with polly it is just stuck and doing nothing at all...

How can I fix this?

```
private async Task StartUp()
{
        await DoStuff());
        // await next task DoStuff1();
        // await next task DoStuff2();
}


private async Task DoStuff()
{
        var data= await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => GetData()));

        // Do stuff with the data
}


private async Task<Data> GetData()
{
     //read filepaths from file.

     var tasks = filePaths
             .Select(f => polly.MyPolicy().Execute(() => ReadDataFromCSV()))
             .ToArray();
    Return await tasks;
}

private Dictionary<string, DateTime?> ReadDataFromCSV()
{

     ///Throw exception....
}

    public PolicyForGetData()
    {
        return Policy
                 .Handle<Exception>()
                 .WaitAndRetry(
                    retryCount: 2,
                    sleepDurationProvider: t => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                    onRetry: (ex, t, i, c) => {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                 );
    }
```

Comment: What policy did you set up? And the code in your question won't compile. You need to create a [MCVE].

Comment: @mason I've updated the thread.

Comment: You still have not provided a [MCVE]. How does PolicuSftpPolicyAsync get used? Why is DoStuff using Task.WhenAll for a single task? Why not just `await GetData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how Polly behaves. Assuming `GetData()` always throws then your application will work like this

1. GetData() throws
2. Polly catches the retries for the first time
3. GetData() throws again
4. Polly catches the retries for the second time
5. GetData() throws for a final time.
6. Polly won't catch or retry the exception because you've only asked it to retry twice, instead the Exception escapes to the `StartUp()` method which prevents `DoStuff1()` and `DoStuff2()` from being called.

For example. The output of this program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Policy
                 .Handle<Exception>()
                 .WaitAndRetry(
                    retryCount: 2,
                    sleepDurationProvider: t => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                    onRetry: (ex, t, i, c) => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnRetry");
                    }
                 )
                 .Execute(() => ErrorMethod());

            Console.WriteLine("We never get here");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Handler");
        }
    }

    private static void ErrorMethod()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Badness");
    }
}
```

Is

```
OnRetry
OnRetry
Exception Handler
```

Comment: Ok, but should the try catch be in the Policy Class where I've created Policy class that I'm injecting to constructor to classes who needs the retry for example? Or should I put the try catch on the method that uses the Policy Class? @Andy Skirrow If we are going to solve the problem in my code. Where should I put the exception handler then?  At the getdata() method?

Comment: @KenKaneki it's difficult to advise how to handle the exception without a bit more context. Does it make sense to Call `DoStuff1()` if `DoStuff()` Fails? How to you plan to report the failure so you can actually diagnose and solve issues in PROD when `DoStuff()` fails?

Comment: In this case, if we can say that dostuff1-2 is indepdent of dostuff1, then yes I want it to continue to the next task.

Comment: You can use a FallbackPolicy to catch the final exception which the retry policy (intentionally) rethrows; see example here: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/665#issuecomment-510559732